# React Router v6.15.0 only renders landing page (path '/'), 404 on all other routes on page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using React Router's latest api. But when deployed on AWS Amplify (OR built and served locally), it only renders the landing page （path '/'）. And it works when navigating to other routes through the landing page （e.g. click a nav link from '/' to '/app-configs', the page can be loaded correctly）. However, when the page is refreshed on route '/app-configs', it's 404...

I've perhaps missed something really basic. Please help！

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Layout />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      { index: true, element: <Landing /> },
      {
        path: 'app-configs',
        element: <AppConfigs />,
      },
      { path: '*', element: <PageNotFound /> },
    ],
  },
]);

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} fallbackElement={<Fallback />} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.15.0",
```

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: @Phil AWS amplify. Or I just use `yarn build && serve build` to test locally... So this requires server side rendering?

Comment: No need, but don't you have some code missing? Have you checked you imported what's necessary? Should you not call createRoot on ReactDom?
Have you checked the documentation?
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router

Comment: @veterini `import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';` imported and createRoot is in the code above `const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));`

Comment: Yeah but i'm saying to call createRoot on ReactDom though? 

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
);

Anyhow i can only advise to follow the documentation which seems plenty usefull with code given

Comment: @Veterini that's the old deprecated syntax

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Phil and @Veterini. I think I've found the solution. It's the same problem as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually) (mark this question as duplicate if needed).

### The short solution for testing is:

To test locally with a react project like this (an SPA with react router), run `yarn build && serve build/ -s`.

> The -s flag tells serve that your app is an SPA and it should respond with index.html to all network calls. Then your app will work
> ([ref answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77231332/11901269) from @Fego)

### But the long answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623117/11901269)

### In case you are using AWS Amplify to deploy your SPA

Follow [the guide here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html#redirects-for-single-page-web-apps-spa) to add a redirect rule through your Amplify console
[image]

Comment: i don't feel i helped at all :D but nice it works. It'll be helpfull to keep it in mind for me as i want to re do some react after a 2 years pause ^^